# How can I keep track of the value of inputs that are dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

**Background:** My app can dynamically add inputs. Each time a new input is created, a new object is created within the **expenses** array.  Each new input accepts a new value and it is displayed to the right of the input.

**Problem:** I am simply trying to -

1. Keep track of the value for each input and
2. Get the total value of all the inputs created

```
<template>
 <div v-for="expense in expenses" :key="expense">
      <input v-model="expense.expensesValue" type="number"> - {{expense.expensesValue}}
 </div>
 <button @click="addInputs()">Add</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return{
      expenses: [{
        expensesValue: 0
      }]
}
},
 methods: {
    addInputs(){
      this.expenses.push({
        expensesValue: 0
      })
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already tracking your expense values since you're using `v-model` on the value of each item in the `expenses` array.  Although to make sure it's getting converted to a number I would use `v-model.number="expense.expensesValue"`.

To get the total you can use a `computed` property and the reduce function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      expenses: [{
        expensesValue: 0
      }]
  },
   methods: {
      addInputs(){
        this.expenses.push({
          expensesValue: 0
        })
      }
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return this.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc += curr.expensesValue;
        return acc;
      }, 0);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
 <div v-for="(expense, idx) in expenses" :key="idx">
      <input v-model.number="expense.expensesValue" type="number"> - {{expense.expensesValue}}
 </div>
<p>total {{ total }}</p>
 <button @click="addInputs()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank! I will look into reduce further